# Complex(?) Excel formula can't be written with VBA to DataBodyRange

Tags: excel, vba, formula

Via VBA, I read formulas from a configuration table where formulas are stored as text, and I write them to other files as real formulas. When such a formula = '=1+1 this will go fine, but the formula

```
'=IFNA(INDEX(tblRoute[ROUTE_ID];MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(tblRoute[RouteFuncKey]=[@RouteFuncKey];0);0));">>> Niet aanwezig!")
```

leads to an error.

I put the configuration table into an array and read the formula from it as follows:

```
strNewFormula = arrTableFieldsWithUpdateAction(6, i)
```

I write the formula with:

```
wbkMDRoutingRCGFile.Worksheets(strTableWorksheet).ListObjects(1).ListColumns(strTableField).DataBodyRange.Formula = strNewFormula
```

An unexpected error occurs:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or objected-defined error.

Comment: Is it happening for all formula or just for some.?  If it is just for some please check whether the formula is right and the names referred are actually available.  + be careful with Quotes and braces..

Comment: If you are writing to `.Formula` you need to use US format formula which use `,` not `;`.  Or write to `.FormulaLocal` instead

Comment: @chrisneilsen: Thank you! Using `.FormulaLocal` solved it!

Answer (score 0):

If the formula is logically correct then it is the argument separator that will give you this trouble.

Formula

```
=IFNA(INDEX(tblRoute[ROUTE_ID];MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(tblRoute[RouteFuncKey]=[@RouteFuncKey];0);0));">>> Niet aanwezig!")
```

through VBA should be

```
=IFNA(INDEX(tblRoute[ROUTE_ID],MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(tblRoute[RouteFuncKey]=[@RouteFuncKey],0),0)),">>> Niet aanwezig!")
```

i.e. all semi-colons shall be replaced by commas!